# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined while using cursors in json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a php script that returns data in json format:

```
[{"text_content":"gdgdsg","text_duration":"15"},{"text_content":"gdgdsg","text_duration":"15"},{"text_content":"gdgdsg","text_duration":"15"},
```

etc.]

and I have a jquery script that parses the input and displays the text on screen:

```
var results;
var cursor = 0;

function myFunction () {
    $.getJSON('list2.php', function(json) {
        results = json.result;
        cursor = 0;

        // Now start printing
        printNext();
    });
}

function printNext(){
    if(cursor == results.length){
        // Reset the cursor back to the beginning.
        cursor = 0;
    }

    // Print the key1 in the div.
    $('#mydiv').hide('fast', function(){ $('#mydiv').html(results[cursor].text_content); $('#mydiv').show('fast'); });

    // Set a delay for the current item to stay
    // Delay is key2 * 1000 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        printNext();
    }, results[cursor].text_duration * 1000);

    // Advance the cursor.
    cursor++;
}
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

in this line:

```
if(cursor == results.length){
```

what might be wrong here?

EDIT:

the php code that returns the data to json is:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT text_content, text_duration from user_text")) {

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
```

Comment: can you provide the php relevant code that sends the json back to the client?

Comment: @taxicala I just did, sorry for not including it at the very beginning

Comment: @taxicala, that's not the problem. Omidam81 has the right answer.

Comment: @JonathanM yes, but you could'nt be sure before checking how he was sending the json to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the callback funtion of getJSON return json data.

```
var results= [];
    var cursor = 0;

function myFunction () {
    $.getJSON('list2.php', function(json) {
        results = json;
        cursor = 0;

        // Now start printing
        printNext();
    });
}

function printNext(){
    if(cursor == results.length){
        // Reset the cursor back to the beginning.
        cursor = 0;
    }

    // Print the key1 in the div.
    $('#mydiv').hide('fast', function(){ $('#mydiv').html(results[cursor].text_content); $('#mydiv').show('fast'); });

    // Set a delay for the current item to stay
    // Delay is key2 * 1000 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        printNext();
    }, results[cursor].text_duration * 1000);

    // Advance the cursor.
    cursor++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your edit, you are already sending the array back to the client, you don't need to do `json.result`.

Replace:

```
results = json.result;
```

with:

```
results = json;
```